# SQL Server examine repetition in column data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, repeat

I have been given a huge excel with data in order to import it into our system. I imported it to an SQL table so that I can do the needed data transformations.
I have come across lots of silly issues.
The latest one which I cannot find a solution is the following:

In the CompanyName, lots of times I have the name repeated twice (not always):

```
[CompanyName]
INTERDYN SA   INTERDYN SA
EARTH TOUR   EARTH TOUR
SOUNDLIGHTS JAJ CYTER
```

There is no pattern as you can see. Is there a cunning way to have the duplicates spotted and remove the twin company name?

Comment: trim the field, pad to even number of chars if needed, divide into two equal parts, trim again... see if one is the same as the other? :)

Comment: Or take the first, say, 8 chars, and see if CharIndex for those is in the substring from position 9 onwards?

Comment: Let's hope that you don't do business with the GPS maker "Tom Tom"

Answer (score 2):

It is just a matter of comparing the first and last part of the string and checking if the middle character is a white space.

```
CREATE TABLE Companies
( 
   id int identity
 , CompanyName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO Companies (CompanyName) 
VALUES ('test') 
     , ('test test') 
     , ('testtest') 
     , ('testz test')

-- Just query the corrected list
SELECT CASE WHEN substring(CompanyName, LEN(CompanyName)/2+1, 1) = ' ' and substring(CompanyName, 1, LEN(CompanyName)/2) = substring(CompanyName, LEN(CompanyName)/2+2, LEN(CompanyName)) 
            THEN substring(CompanyName, 1, LEN(CompanyName)/2) 
            ELSE CompanyName 
       END
FROM Companies

-- update the incorrect values
UPDATE Companies
   SET CompanyName = substring(CompanyName, 1, LEN(CompanyName)/2) 
 WHERE substring(CompanyName, LEN(CompanyName)/2+1, 1) = ' ' 
   AND substring(CompanyName, 1, LEN(CompanyName)/2) = substring(CompanyName, LEN(CompanyName)/2+2, LEN(CompanyName))

select * from Companies

drop table Companies
```